# Trying to process A rectangle type of detection instead of QR but it throws errors

Tags: ios, swift

```
func processQRCodeImage(_ image: UIImage) {
    var qrCodeLink = ""
    let detector: CIDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeRectangle, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])!
    let ciImage: CIImage = CIImage(image: image)!
    
    let features = detector.features(in: ciImage)
    if let features = features as? [CIRectangleFeature] {
        for feature in features {
            qrCodeLink += feature.messageString!
        }
    }
    
    if qrCodeLink.isEmpty {
        failedQRCoderead()
    } else {
        found(code: qrCodeLink)
        onBackPressed?()
    }
}
```

I was switching the Detector scanner from QR to Rectangle type of detection but on Rectangle type of detection I cannot take the feature.messageString out of CIRectangleFeature, while on CIQRCodeFeature it works. Only what I had changed was ofType: CIDetectorTypeQRCode into CIDetectorTypeRectangle and features as? [CIQRCodeFeature] into features as? [CIRectangleFeature]

Comment: So what error does it throw?

Comment: Value of type 'CIRectangleFeature' has no member 'messageString'

Comment: "throws errors", this phrase is usually associated with runtime errors but the error message implies you have a compilation error.

Comment: well in the app i have a view with the button "choose from gallery" where I need to choose from the gallery a pdf417 format to scan and when I choose then it nothing happens and it just brings me back to the view where the button "choose from gallery"...